# Ideas on why JS causes rails validations to be ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application that uses `$('form').submit()`, however if it fails the validation once and then it is clicked again it completely ignores the validations and generates a routing error.  Now, If I use the regular button it does not do this unless the JQuery submit exists with it.  Why do you think that is?

**Update:**  JQuery finds the form values looking for anything within the `<form>` tags.

Comment: how do you get the form values?

Comment: You really need to expand upon your question I'm afraid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was not related to the JavaScript at all.  What was happening is a variable was getting a value of nil causing a routing error for the path.  Adding a check for nil and reassigning it if it is fixed it.